# About the tag `graph`

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There currently is a tag [graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph). I wanted to change it to `graphs` because most of our tags use the plural, but it would not let me (supposedly because the tags are too similar). Is there an easy way to change [graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) to its plural short of removing it from all questions and *then* creating the proper form?

Answer (score 4):

Someone with a ♦ can do the renaming.

[Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/graph-theory), [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tags/graph-theory) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/graph-theory) all use `graph-theory` (SO also has some graph theory under [`graph`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/graph), together with plots); Math uses [`graph`](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/graph) for a function graph). So we should use `graph-theory` as well or at least as a synonym. I favor the direction [graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) → [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory), making the master tag the most explicit one.

Comment: But do algorithms on graphs or even using graphs really graph theory? I don't think so.

Comment: I guess we could use [tag:combinatorial-algorithms], but those are not exclusive to graphs.

Comment: I renamed graph -> graphs; if you think graph-theory should be  a synonym, please propose that separately.